# how to add matching records from second table to the first table row

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

base table:

| bid | b_name | b_lname | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Nathan | aa |
| 2 | Brand | Ba | bb |
| 3 | Bob | Do | cc |
| 4 | Alice | Sia | dd |

design table:

| id | designname | designdescription | speed | bid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | test description | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | test2 | test description2 | 21 | 1 |

The following query i have tried

```sql
select * from base b inner join design d on b.bid=d.bid
```

desired json response

```json
{
"bid" :  1,
"b_name" : "john",
"b_lname" : "nathan",
"description" : "aa",
"designpoints" :
[
  {
 "id" :  1, 
 "designname" :  "test1",
 "designdescription" : "test description",
 "speed" :  20,
 "bid" :  1

  },
 {
 "id" :  2, 
 "designname" :  "test2",
 "designdescription" : "test description2",
 "speed" :  21,
 "bid" :  1

  }
]


}
```

desired output

| bid | b_name | b_lname | description | ConcatOutput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Nathan | aa | #1#test1#test description#20#1 |
| 2 | Brand | Ba | bb |  |
| 3 | Bob | Do | cc |  |
| 4 | Alice | Sia | dd |  |

Comment: How is C# relevant? and do you want a JSON output or table output?

Comment: Do you use an ORM like Entity framework or NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

For your JSON output, you can use nested `FOR JSON PATH` clauses

```sql
SELECT
  b.bid,
  b.b_name,
  b.b_lname,
  b.description,
  designpoints = (
    SELECT
      d.id,
      d.designname,
      d.designdescription,
      d.speed,
      d.bid
    FROM design d
    WHERE d.bid = b.bid
    FOR JSON PATH
  )
FROM base b
WHERE b.bid = 1
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

For the aggregated output, you can use a combination of `CONCAT_WS` (which adds a separator) and `STRING_AGG` (for multiple rows)

```sql
SELECT
  b.bid,
  b.b_name,
  b.b_lname,
  b.description,
  ConcatOutput = (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT_WS('#',
          '',
          d.id,
          d.designname,
          d.designdescription,
          d.speed,
          d.bid
        ),
        '#'
      )
    FROM design d
    WHERE d.bid = b.bid
  )
FROM base b;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/j8CULENL)